# Why are users able to visit my website even after blocking ftom htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have added following code in my htaccess file but still users from **enow.com** are able to access my website. why is it so?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ecosia\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hao123\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buenosearch\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} findgofind\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} zlsite\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} searchlock\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} monstercrawler\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} start\.fyi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} searchencrypt\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} enow\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} searchprivacy\.co [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} my-seo-promotion-service\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} perform-like-alibabaity\.info[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} worldwide-seo-services\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} accueil-search\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} goq-it\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} home-hp-search\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} dataxu\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} gamer\.com[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} when\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mysearch\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} info\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} monstercrawler\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Without knowing anything i would assume the referer also includes the path and not just the host and then your rules do not match. Apart from that why would you want to annoy users? An other aproch could be using a robots.txt to not be listed on this sites (ofc noone enforces them to listen to your robots.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*ecosia\.org.*$ [NC,OR]
...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*monstercrawler\.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```